# Test dynamic import in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, code-splitting

I'm trying to test a custom hook I created that dynamically imports `@vimeo/player`.

Relevant part of `useVideoPlayer`- hook:

```
   useEffect(() => {
        async function setup() {
            const { default: Player } = await import('@vimeo/player');
            playerRef.current = new Player(
                playerRef.current,
                playerConfig,
            );

            playerRef.current.on('loaded', () => setIsLoading(false));
            playerRef.current.getVideoTitle().then((t) => setTitle(t)).catch(handleErrorCallback);
        }


        if (playerRef?.current) {
            setup();
        }

        return () => playerRef.current.destroy && playerRef.current.destroy();
    }, [playerRef]);
```

This is the test asserting state is set correctly:

```
 jest.mock('@vimeo/player', () => class MockPlayer {
    constructor() {
        this.events = new Map();
    }
    on(event, handler) {
        this.events[event] = handler;
    }
    trigger(event) {
        this.events[event]();
    }
 
    getVideoTitle() {
        return Promise.resolve('title.mp4');
    }
    destroy() {
        return jest.fn();
    }
});
...



   test.each([
                ['loaded', 'isLoading', true, false],
                ['bufferstart', 'isBuffering', false, true],
                ['play', 'isPlaying', false, true],
            ])('event: %s should set state: %s from %s to %s',
                async (event, state, valueBefore, valueAfter) => {
                    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(useVideoPlayer, {
                        initialProps: { playerRef: ref, playerConfig },
                    });
                    console.log(result.current.playerRef.current);
                    /*
                    MockPlayer {
                      events: Map(0) {
                      loaded: [Function (anonymous)],
                      bufferstart: [Function (anonymous)],
                      bufferend: [Function (anonymous)],
                      play: [Function (anonymous)],
                      pause: [Function (anonymous)],
                      timeupdate: [Function (anonymous)]
                     }
                    }
                   */

                    expect(result.current[state]).toEqual(valueBefore);
    
                    act(() => {
                        result.current.playerRef.current.trigger(event);
                    });
                    await waitForNextUpdate(); // need both, act and waitForNextUpdate to get rid of warnings
                    expect(result.current[state]).toEqual(valueAfter);
                });
```

The test succeeds when I import `Player` non-dynamically, but fail with the dynamic import. What I don't understand is why the methods(`on`, `trigger`) are not available on `MockPlayer` - could someone help me understand? I guess I somehow have to wait until the promise of the dynamic import resolves?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `await waitForNextUpdate()` and adding `await waitForValueToChange(() => result.playerRef.current)` fixed the issue.